# JUnit Testing - Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I am using Intellij Idea 14CE. I want to test my class `DistanceOfRoute`

```
import java.util.*;
/*
    Definition of DistanceOfRoute.java class
    Finds distances of directly defined routes
    1. The distance of the route A-B-C.
    2. The distance of the route A-D.
    3. The distance of the route A-D-C.
    4. The distance of the route A-E-B-C-D.
    5. The distance of the route A-E-D.
 */
public class DistanceOfRoute {
    //declaration of the HashTable
    public Hashtable <Town, Path> trip;
    //constructor
    public DistanceOfRoute (){
        this.trip = new Hashtable<Town, Path>();
    }
    public int distanceOfDirectRoutes(ArrayList <Town> nodes){
        //initialize distance and depth variables to 0, before calculation
        int distance = 0;
        int depth = 0;
        //there must be at least 2 town to get the route distance.
        if(nodes.size() < 2){
            System.out.println("THERE SHOULD BE AT LEAST 2 TOWNS.");
        }
        for(int index = 0; index <= nodes.size(); index++){
            //check whether index is in the HashTable.If not, print "NO SUCH ROUTE."
            if(!this.trip.containsKey(nodes.get(index))){
                System.out.println("NO SUCH ROUTE");
            }
            /*if the index is in the HashTable, control whether any corresponding
              route from key to the next town is available.If so, add weight of the
              path to the distance and increase depth by 1.
            */
            else
            {
                Path newPath = this.trip.get(nodes.get(index));
                while(newPath != null){
                    if(newPath.destinationTown.equals(nodes.get(index + 1))){
                        distance = distance + newPath.weightOfPath;
                        depth = depth + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    //Continue with the next path.
                    newPath = newPath.nextPath;
                }
            }
            //increase index after each turn of the loop
            index++;
        }
        return distance;
    }
}
```

So I wrote my test class as

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.*;

public class DistanceOfRouteTest {

Town A,B,C,D,E;
Path path1;
@org.junit.Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    A = new Town("A");
    B = new Town("B");
    C = new Town("C");
    D = new Town("D");
    E = new Town("E");

    path1 = new Path();
    path1.trip.put(A, new Path(A, B, 5).nextPath(new Path(A, D, 5).nextPath(new Path(A, E, 7))));
    path1.trip.put(B, new Path(B, C, 4));
    path1.trip.put(C, new Path(C, D, 8).nextPath(new Path(C, E, 2)));
    path1.trip.put(D, new Path(D, C, 8).nextPath(new Path(D, E, 6)));
    path1.trip.put(E, new Path(E, B, 3));

}
@Test
public void testDistanceOfDirectRoutes_ABC() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Town> distance = new ArrayList<Town>();
    distance.add(A);
    distance.add(B);
    distance.add(C);
    assertEquals("ABC route have a length of 9. ", 9, path1.distanceOfDirectRoutes(distance));
}
@Test
public void testDistanceOfDirectRoutes_AD() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Town> distance = new ArrayList<Town>();
    distance.add(A);
    distance.add(D);
    assertEquals("AD route have a length of 5 ", 5, path1.distanceOfDirectRoutes(distance));
}
@Test
public void testDistanceOfDirectRoutes_ADC() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Town> distance = new ArrayList<Town>();
    distance.add(A);
    distance.add(C);
    assertEquals("ADC route have a length of 13 ", 13, path1.distanceOfDirectRoutes(distance));
}
@Test
public void testDistanceOfDirectRoutes_AEBCD() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Town> distance = new ArrayList<Town>();
    distance.add(A);
    distance.add(E);
    distance.add(B);
    distance.add(C);
    distance.add(D);
    assertEquals(" AEBCD route have a length of 22", 22, path1.distanceOfDirectRoutes(distance));
}
@Test
public void testDistanceOfDirectRoutes_AED() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Town> distance = new ArrayList<Town>();
    distance.add(A);
    distance.add(E);
    distance.add(D);
    assertEquals("NO SUCH ROUTE EXISTS ", -1, path1.distanceOfDirectRoutes(distance));

}
```

}

The Town.java class

```
/*
Definition of Town.java class
Node of the graph is considered as a Town
*/
public class Town {
//variables
public String name;
public boolean isVisited;
//default constructor
public Town (){
    name = "no name yet.";
    isVisited = false;
}
//constructor
public Town(String name){
    this.name = name;
    this.isVisited = false;
}
//Accessor and mutuator methods
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public boolean isVisited(){
    return isVisited;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public void setVisited(boolean isVisited){
    this.isVisited = isVisited;
}
}
```

Path.java class

```
/*
Definition of Path.java class
Edge of the graph is considered as a Path between two towns.
*/
public class Path {
//Variables
public Town startingTown;
public Town destinationTown;
public int weightOfPath;
public Path nextPath;

public Path(){
    startingTown = null;
    destinationTown = null;
    weightOfPath = 0;
    nextPath = null;
}
public Path(Town startingTown, Town destinationTown, int    weightOfPath){
    this.startingTown = startingTown;
    this.destinationTown = destinationTown;
    this.weightOfPath = weightOfPath;
    this.nextPath = null;
}
public Path nextPath(Path nextPath) {
    this.nextPath = nextPath;
    return this;
}
public Town getStartingTown(){
    return startingTown;
}
public Town getDestinationTown(){
    return destinationTown;
}
public int getWeightOfPath(){
    return weightOfPath;
}
public Path getNextPath(){
    return nextPath;
}
public void setStartingTown(Town startingTown) {
    this.startingTown = startingTown;
}
public void setDestinationTown(Town setDestinationTown){
    this.destinationTown = destinationTown;
}
public void setWeightOfPath(int weightOfPath){
    this.weightOfPath = weightOfPath;
}
public void setNextPath(Path nextPath){
    this.nextPath = nextPath;
}
}
```

The test gives an different errors that says 'cannot resolve symbol junit', 'cannot resolve symbol trip' ,'cannot resolve symbol path1'.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you using maven to build this? Have you got Junit in your class path?

Comment: yes I use maven to build this.Junit is included to the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@oddly I see only one major error in your code that Path class don't have any method/var named 'trip'. 'trip' is a HashTable you defined in class 'DistanceOfRoute' & your are trying to access through Path instance.

No error related to JUnit seen. I assume you have already imported 'org.junit.Assert.*' for assertion

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven, ensure you have the dependency for junit specified, and in the correct scope:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven, make sure you have the junit jar somewhere on your classpath when you run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your variables global:

```
Town A, B, C, D, E;
Path path1;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    A = new Town("A");
    B = new Town("B");
    C = new Town("C");
    D = new Town("D");
    E = new Town("E");
    path1 = new Path();
    path1.trip.put(A, new Path(A, B, 5).nextPath(new Path(A, D, 5).nextPath(new Path(A, E, 7))));
    path1.trip.put(B, new Path(B,C,4));
    path1.trip.put(C, new Path(C, D, 8).nextPath(new Path(C, E, 2)));
    path1.trip.put(D, new Path(D, C, 8).nextPath(new Path(D, E, 6)));
    path1.trip.put(E, new Path(E, B, 3));
}
//tests here
```

Also rather then doing the full annotation declaration you can just use `@Test` or `@Before` etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot..I did the changes that you said.But it still says that 'cannot resolve symbol junit' at the import statement.Same problem exists for every trip and DistanceOfRoute terms.

Comment: You may not have the JUnit dependency on the classpath? Not sure what else it could be

Comment: @blm I would go further and make A, B, C and D private final fields and initialize them where they are defined. It would also be better style to have the fields named a, b, c and d.

Comment: I have just edited the question and added related classes.Same problem still continues.I can't fix it.